# Products name in webshop, h2 or strong tag?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

In a webshop, on the category page where im listing the products from SQL, should I put the products name into `<strong>` tags, or just `<h2>`?

Now:

```
<h2><a href="#" title="Termék név">Product name</a></h2>
```

Or:

```
<h2><a href="#" title="Termék név"><strong>Product name</strong></a></h2>
```

Is this important in SEO?

Comment: Note that asking for SEO advice (i.e., what is better for SEO) is off-topic here. Such questions can be asked on [webmasters.se]. Here on Stack Overflow you can ask which markup should be used according to the HTML standard; not according to some (secret) search engine algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strong is mainly used for styling. As using some CSS rule, via a class, on your h2 would achieve the same goal (or better), don't bother yourself with these strong tag.

There is no real gain using strong tag from a seo point in this case, as h2 is more relevant than strong, stick to h2.

Answer (score -1):

I would avoid using the strong tag in general, as you should really do all styling (bold, italics, etc.) with CSS. Use a header tag OR apply styling to your a tag.